# PySpark: Evaluating specific columns together

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a Spark dataframe that looks like the following:

```
+---+----+---+---+
| a | b  | c | d |
+---+----+-------+
|13 | 43 | 67| 3 |
+---+----+---+---+
```

Is it possible to choose specific columns to evaluate together to produce the following?

```
+----+----+---+---+-----+-----+-----------+
|  a | b  | c | d | a+b | c-b | a+b / c-b |
+----+----+-------+-----+-----+-----------+
| 13 | 43 | 67| 3 |  56 |  24 |   2.33    |
+----+----+---+---+-----+-----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use `selectExpr` or `withColumn` to add extra columns:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

(
    df.withColumn("a+b", expr("a + b"))
    .withColumn("c-b", expr("c - b"))
    .withColumn("a+b / c-b", expr("(a + b) / (c - b)"))
    .show()
)
```

Comment: For long term value, please explain why this code solves OP's issue. Code only answers are frowned upon. Explanations help future visitors learn, and apply this knowledge to similar issues that have in their own code. They are also more likely to be upvoted. Consider editing to improve your answer, and keep quality of SO Answers high.